# How to align braces and \mid in a set in order to get the same height

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, alignment, vector

### Main question

> How to align braces and \mid in a set in order to get the same height?

### Code:

My following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$G_1=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ -5 \end{pmatrix} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$
\end{document}
```

compiles to:
[image: tex-1]

Does this is a better visualization than:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$G_1=\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ -5 \end{pmatrix} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$
\end{document}
```

which compiles to:
[image: tex-2]

?

---

### Other questions

1. How do I align the negative numbers of the vectors correctly?
2. How do I manage to change the relational symbol `\mid` to a bigger one that fits the height of the vectors/braces?
3. Which is the best way to visualize G_1 if none of the visualizations above are good enough?

Comment: what do you mean by "formal" and "fancy" here? (I know what the words mean, but I can not guess what you mean in this context)

Comment: `\middle\vert` should grow the vertical bar in a `\left...\right` construct.

Comment: Sry for the misleading words. I wanted to express, that the braces, \mid and all vectors have the same height. Furthermore, it would be good, if the negative numbers are aligned correctly

Comment: @DavidCarlisle alright, I will change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `spalign` package you can obtain same result of the best answers of @Bernard and @Steven B. Segletes. The code is not very long.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spalign}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[G_1=\left\{ \spalignvector[r]{1 -2 3 4}+\lambda\spalignvector[r]{1 -2 3 4} \middle\vert\ \lambda\in \mathbb{R}\right\}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the `pmatrix*[r]` environment, from `mathtools`, in a medium-sized version thanks to the `medsize` environment from `nccmath`. Also, I used a `\set` command based on `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` (again from `mathtools`), which uses two arguments, separated by a semi-colon:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\newenvironment{pmmatrix*}[1][c]{\medsize\begin{pmatrix*}[#1]}{ \end{pmatrix*}\endmedsize}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak\mathopen{}#2\nonscript\,}}

\begin{document}

\[\set*{\begin{pmmatrix*}[r]1\\ -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmmatrix*} + \lambda\begin{pmmatrix*}[r]-2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ -5 \end{pmmatrix*}; \lambda\in\mathbf{R}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a different approach of the problem!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\begin{document}

$G_1=\left\{ \parenVectorstack[r]{ 1 \\ -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 } + 
  \lambda \parenVectorstack[r]{ -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ -5 } 
  \middle\vert\, \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is what I actually was looking for but one last question: How can you change the spacing of the vertical line so that it has the same space to the vector and the lambda?

Comment: @Doesbaddel Either add `\!` before `\middle\vert` or add `\,` after `\middle\vert`.  I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Doesbaddel Note: you can also change the row spacing (baselineskip) prior to building the vector stacks, with `\setstackgap{L}{14pt}` (currently `\baselineskip` = `12pt`).